# Typescript Record with know property of a different type

Tags: typescript

I have this Record type and custom type

```js
type Rest = Record<string, string[]>
type Special = { specialProp: string };
type All = Rest & Special;
```

but whenever I try to do:

```js
const obj: All = { specialProp: "foo", prop2: ["bar", "baz"] };
```

I get this error

```
Type '{ specialProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'All'.
  Type '{ specialProp: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string[]>'.
    Property 'specialProp' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
```

How can I fix this error? I tried changing the order of the intersection but that didn't work

Comment: This is unfortunately not directly possible in TypeScript; see the linked q/a for more information and various workarounds.